# How to change the UITableViewCell content view by IBAction?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ibaction, nsindexpath

I have a UITableView with many cells and all the cells are going into one xib view, i have 2 buttons in that xib view - Up, Down. 
What i want to do is to jump to the next/back cell content when pressing one of these buttons, the content view need to change, like Mail.app, Reeder app etc...

this is what i tried to do but it didn't work:

```
  NSIndexPath *currentPath = [tipsGuideViewTv indexPathForSelectedRow];
  NSIndexPath *nextPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexVariable.row+1         inSection:indexVariable.section];

 [self.navigationController popToViewController:nextPath animated:YES];
```

I search the web for solution but i didn't find exactly what i mean.
Someone know how to made it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you mean to use currentPath instead of indexVariable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSIndexPath *currentPath = [tipsGuideViewTv indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSIndexPath *nextPath    = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentPath.row+1 
                                              inSection:currentPath.section];

[tipsGuideViewTv selectRowAtIndexPath:nextPath animated:YES];
```

**EDIT per comments**

```
// To make it function the same as if they had tapped the row, do the following:
// Only call the methods that are implemented in your controller.
[tipsGuideViewTv tableView:tipsGuideViewTv willSelectRowAtIndexPath:nextPath];
[tipsGuideViewTv tableView:tipsGuideViewTv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:nextPath];
```

Make sure that the new index path is valid though (ie you aren't already t the end of the table).

Comment: If i go back to the UITableView from the view i see the next row selected, but i want to change the view to that next cell. Like the Mail.app, there is two arrow buttons that change the view to the next/back cell. I want to navigate to that cell via pushViewController